# Can I speed up the 'raspicam_node' publish speed of OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, ros

We're trying to develop self-driving using ros and turtlebot. I'm trying to get an image from raspicam_node and drive with a lane ceremony, but It's too slow to publish from raspicam_node on turtleBot3.Of course, it's slow to get it from a remote PC, so it's hard to get a image.

So we tested it to slow it down by just storing images and printing "received" into the console. However, we have verified that the text in the Console is output once every 10 seconds. As a result, I think this is not the overhead of the code we implemented.

The connection between the TurtleBot and the Remote PC is connected to the 100Mbps 'IpTime' wireless network machine.

Is it because of this slow wireless connection or do I have to set the raspicam_node of TurtleBot3?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not do any processing/posting on OpenCV or ROS in the Raspberry PI. It is a pretty slow platform and does not allow you to do complicated operations.

My suggestion is by pass all ROS and OpenCV on Raspberry PI when dealing with large image data.

(1)If you really have to use ROS, at least **use compressed stream** from

See here to know how it is done http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport

```
rosrun image_transport republish [in_transport] in:=<in_base_topic> [out_transport] out:=<out_base_topic>
```

(2) The other low-cost way to  send to ground is using **v4l2 driver** so its either

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
cvlc v4l2:///dev/video0 --v4l2-width 1920 --v4l2-height 1080 --v4l2-chroma h264 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst=0.0.0.0:22322}'
```

or using ffmpeg directly to send over

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -framerate 30 -video_size 800x448 -i /dev/video0 -i /home/pi/Desktop/sound/logo.png -codec:v h264 -r 30 -s 800x448 -bf 0 -g 30 -bufsize 8000k -maxrate 8000k -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2:enable='gte(t,1)'" -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -f h264 udp://192.168.5.10:23003
```

You must keep the **-preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency** on

In this way, the lag should be minimal as you dont do any processing but just forward over the internet. In GCS, you can use opencv or other tools necessary to get from http or udp server address

Then you do whatever you want with the image stream on the ground control station. E.g. monocular depth estimation, object detection, localization.

If necessary reduce the SIZE of the camera stream to 640*480., it will accelerate your output speed. Even lowest quality wireless should be able to handle compressed 640*480 stream.

The ros only need to handle control command at low update frequecy